# Number and size of raster clusters in each polygon with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, vector

I project a raster file of human settlement to an administrative territory layer. How can I count how many settlements there are (as the red speckles) in each administrative polygon? Also, I'd like to know the size of each settlement.

[image]

I tried vectorise the raster file after sieving. But then the question turns into "How to count the number and size of polygons in each polygon"--which I also do not know.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would vectorize the raster, dissolve, multipart to singlepart to create one polygon per settlement. Then use a virtual layer.

You need to have an id column in both your layers for this to work. You can create them using field calculator and the expression `@row_number`.

The same settlement in two zones will be counted twice

```sql
select  z.id as zoneid, 
        z.geometry, 
        count(s.id) as settlementcount, 
        round( coalesce( sum(st_area(st_intersection(z.geometry, s.geometry))), 0), 2) as settlementarea
from zones as z --replace zones with the name of your zones layer
left join settlement as s --replace settlement with the name of your settlement layer
on st_intersects(z.geometry, s.geometry)
group by zoneid, z.geometry
```

[image]

Right click and export the virtual layer to make it permanent

Comment: Thanks! I have a further question during vectorising the raster file.  I want only the small red speckles to be vectorised into polygons, but the vectorisation tool would turn the general background (the grey areas in the first picture) into some big polygons. For this small county I can just manually delete the polygons I don’t want, but it seems unlikely to do this for all 2000+ counties.

Comment: You can select them by area, you dont have to do it manually

Comment: My settlementarea returns 0 for all rows.  Is it because I need to somehow define "z.geometry"?

Comment: What coordinate system are your data in?

Comment: I think it is WGS 84, if I understand the question correctly.